# I would like my video to return to the start and display the poster when finished

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Not sure why the code below doesn't execute.  I have also tried using currentTime=1 to set the video to the first second once finished...this didn't work either.

```
<div class="full-video">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video = document.getElementById('video1');
        if(video){
            video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
            window.location = 'https://example.org';
            });
        }
    </script>
    <video controls width="100%"  poster="images/training-program.jpg" id="video1">
        <source src="files/uploads/videos/Training.webm"  type='video/webm'>
        <source src="files/uploads/videos/Training.mp4"  type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you redirecting to other location when video ends ?

Comment: I was trying to get the page to refresh thus bringing the video back to the beginning and displaying the poster image that I want to see once the video finishes.  I would rather not do a refresh as it's annoying but can't find an alternative right now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the poster and return to start, this should work

```
 var video = document.getElementById('video1');
    if(video){
        video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        video.currentTime = 0;
        video.load();
        });
    }
```

And I still don't understand why are you trying to change the location of the page when video ends.

Comment: This did not work for me.  The video played through to the end and the screen went black and remained at the end of the video.  I am testing this on a window 7 machine with google chrome. NOTE: I put an alert statement after "var video" and it executed.  The one I placed after "if (video)" did not execute.  Obviously it is not recognizing "video" and I don't know why.